# xandros-explorer (Xandros File Manager) custom menu items

Tags: netbook, eee-pc, xandros

Is there any way to get custom menu item in right-click, instruments or at least hotkey that will run specific program for a selected filesystem item or current folder (like open terminal by Ctrl+T)?

I've looked through [usr/share/apps/XandrosFileManager](http://sysinf0.klabs.be/usr/share/apps/XandrosFileManager/?dist=xandros4.0-xn;arch=), but found nothing useful.